# Datums in compound CRSs

Tags: datum, coordinate-system

Is there some specific constraint regarding *vertical* and *geodetic* **datums** within a compound Coordinate Reference System (CRS)? E.g. if the ellipsoid model should be the same or not, or if the vertical datum can be barometric, etc.

As also *engineering* CRSs can be compound with geodetic 2D CRSs, then I don't believe there are such sort of constraints.

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably best asked on the [MetaCRS mailing list](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/MetaCRS#Mailing_list), which might give a more practical answer based on community experience. In short, I do believe that the vertical and horizontal datums of a compound CRS need not be the same, though in practices this isn't such a great idea. It's more a matter of what software can consume, and not so many softwares are so great at consuming compound CRSs anyway right now.

Comment: Thank you Howard, I was not aware of the MetaCRS project: I'm joining right now.